# How to fix an Error in Preference Manager

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

In my Android project I gotta read the link from firebase, after that read another from the HTML code, save it to Preference and open it. I tried to find the answer how to do it here, but  I didn't, and after that I decided to ask chatGPT how to write such code. And it wrote. But when I pasted it to Android Studio, I discovered the error (in class MyWebViewClient):

> Unresolved reference

`PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences` has been crossed out, and the context `this@WebActivity` was highlighted in red.

What's the problem?

Here's my code:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.preference.PreferenceManager
import android.util.Log
import android.webkit.*
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.template.databinding.ActivityWebBinding
import java.util.*

class WebActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var binding: ActivityWebBinding
    val uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityWebBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val webIntent: Intent = intent
        val domen = webIntent.getStringExtra("domen")
        val url="$domen/?packageid=$packageName&usserid=$uuid&getz=Asia/Yekaterinburg&getr=utm_source=google-play&utm_medium=organic"
        Log.d("The link", url)

        val webSettings: WebSettings = binding.webView.settings
        webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true

        binding.webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(binding.webView,true)
        binding.webView.webViewClient = MyWebViewClient()

        val htmlContent = "<html><body><a href='$url'>https://superaso.xyz/test//</a></body></html>"
        binding.webView.loadData(htmlContent, "text/html", "UTF-8")

        var rememberedLink = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("remembered_link", null);
        if (rememberedLink != null) {
            binding.webView.loadUrl(rememberedLink);
        } else {
            val maIntent=Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(maIntent)
        }
    }

    class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient() {
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
            // Save the clicked link to preferences
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this@WebActivity).edit()
                .putString("remembered_link", url).apply()

            // Load the clicked link in the webview
            view.loadUrl(url)
            return true
        }
    }
}
```